# If $x$ is in an interval $(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, then $|x|>|x_0|-|\delta|$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I want a quick and tidy proof (i.e. without splitting into positives and negatives cases and stuff) that if $x\in(x_0-\delta, x_0+\delta)$, then $|x|>|x_0|-|\delta|$. I've been struggling with this for over an hour now and I can't think of anything. I feel like the triangle inequality should be important here, but I just can't think of it. I'm very frustrated right now because I'm guessing that this is extremely trivial.

If the identity is in fact not true, then please turn your attention to the case where $x_0\neq 0$ and $\delta=\frac{|x_0|}{2}$. I'm $99.99\%$ sure that the identity is true in that case.  Again I'm sorry for the stupid question but I'm really at the end of my wits here.

Comment: Is delta positive? Then you can show $|x| + |\delta| \ge |x+\delta| > |x_0|$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas yup ok I'm going to frickin' die of shame. Time to hold an early funeral for my intellect. Thanks.

Comment: If $\delta \leq 0$, then the statement $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)$ doesn't make much sense now does it? So I don't think you need absolute values around $\delta$

Comment: @frogeyedpeas wait wait wait how I do I show $|x+\delta|>|x_0|$? If $x=-4\in(-5,-1)$ then $|-4+2|\not> |-3|$

Comment: So infimum x = $x_0 - \delta$ so the infimum value of $x + \delta$ would be $x_0 + \delta - \delta = x_0$ so we can conclude: $x + \delta \ge x_0$ (since we are using open intervals we have a strict inequality). Hmm... this is not the absolute value inequality you want

Comment: Yea I spoke too soon, I forgot that the absolute value can’t be freely taken on both sides

Comment: @frogeyedpeas seems we were both tricked by the math gods

Comment: So if $x_0 $ and $x_0 + \delta$ are positive then this collection of comments constitutes a proof, so the hard part is if they are of different signs or both negative: namely $x_0$ is negative and $x_0 + \delta$ positive,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \Leftrightarrow |\, x - x_0 \,| < \delta$.

Using the reverse triangle inequality:

$$ \big | \, |x| - |x_0| \, \big| \leq \big| \, x - x_0 \, \big| < \delta.$$

Comment: Is the rest basically flipping the thing inside the abs val on the left side and then removing the abs val?

Comment: @D.R. Yup, that works.